# can not change color of line using rgb value using cairo in pygtk

Tags: python, pygtk, cairo

I am drawing on drawing area using cairo in pygtk.
I set color of line using this func:

```
cr.set_source_rgb(203,12,41)
```

but it showing white color instead of this color `#CB0C33` it is like red rose color.
So please can any one tell me how to change color of line to any color using cairo in pygtk.
Please help me.
thank you in advanced...

Answer (score 3):

[set_source_rgb](http://www.cairographics.org/documentation/cairomm/reference/classCairo_1_1Context.html#aff3f3fc62bdf862646bb8cc568c30b2a) expects you to pass floating point values from 0 to 1, where 1 should correspond to FF. Pls, check if the code below would work for you:

```
color = gtk.gdk.Color('#CB0C33')
cr.set_source_rgb(float(color.red) / 65535, 
                  float(color.green) / 65535, 
                  float(color.blue) / 65535)
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: I did not know about gtk.gdk.Color, that is great news to me! Thanks!